# Eloquent relationship returning can't convert to string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to map an existing one to one relationship in my database using Eloquent following the Laravel tutorial and I'm receiving a string conversion error.

I have to use an existing database that is used by other program, so I can't change the database structure.

This are my models:

Pessoa.php

```
 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log; use
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Pessoa extends Model {
     protected $table = 'pessoas';
     public function estadoCivil(){
         //return EstadoCivil::find($this->estado_civil_id);
         return $this->hasOne('App\Models\EstadoCivil', 'estado_civil_id');
     } 
 }
```

EstadoCivil.php
namespace App\Models;

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 class EstadoCivil extends Model
 {
     protected $table = 'estados_civis';
 }
```

I don't know what to do, but I am getting this error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne could not be converted to string

I searched for typos and other mistakes and couldn't find anything. I'm not even trying to convert anything to string to get this error, the types in the database for the id and the foreign key are the same too.

Here is the controller that is using it:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Pessoa as Pessoa;

class Eu extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function dadosCompletos(Request $request){
        return Pessoa::find($request->user()->pessoa_id)->estadoCivil();
    }
}
```

If I just use `return Pessoa::find($request->user()->pessoa_id)` it works fine and returns the data correctly from pessoas table.

Comment: The model definitions look fine. How are you _using_ the relationship? Chances are that's where the issue is.

Comment: have you checked the types of columns in database?

Comment: @eminem yes, both are Integer.

Comment: @AkenRoberts updated with the controller.

Comment: To Aken's point, though, where are you getting the error?  IE what are you printing out?  If you are just trying to print the object, and not a field, this may be the cause.  In other words are you trying to print a field via $obj->field, or just $obj?

Comment: @Watercayman I'm using this for an api call, the result should be a json object. return Pessoa::find($request->user()->pessoa_id) works fine.

Comment: If the object is pulled correctly from the db (whatever the result of the estadoCivil() returns), then it sounds like the issue is with your translation to the json object -- perhaps not using json_encode or compact?

Comment: You have to use `->estadoCivil` instead of `->estadoCivil()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks. Post this comment as answer so I can accept it. To everyone who commented thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are returning the relation not the actual  EstadoCivil collection.
use `return Pessoa::find($request->user()->pessoa_id)->estadoCivil` without parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `->estadoCivil` instead of `->estadoCivil()`